# Trying to resolve issue with React Context

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-context

My colleague has identified a possible issue with React Context.  He has kindly created two sets of code in CodeSandBox to demonstrate the problem.

**Redux version (works without any problems)**

1. Using Chrome, please open this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-test-6hqzp
2. Open the standalone link in another tab: https://6hqzp.csb.app/
3. In the standalone tab, open Chrome DevTools and click on the React DevTools Components tab.
4. In the configuration, ensure that "Highlight updates when components render" is checked.
5. Type in the textbox and notice the colored rectangles only appear around Comp[onent] 1 & 2.
6. This is our base case, illustrating what we expect to re-render with each keypress.

**Context version (illustrates the issue)**

1. Using Chrome, please open this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/context-test-1288z
2. Open the standalone link in another tab: https://1288z.csb.app/
3. In the standalone tab, open Chrome DevTools and click on the React DevTools Components tab.
4. In the configuration, ensure that "Highlight updates when components render" is checked.
5. Type in the textbox.  Notice that now, both Component 3 AND the overall app are BOTH being re-rendered with each keypress.

It's also important to note that the nested Context pattern in `AppContext` derives from Kent C. Dodds: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

I am wondering if my colleague has found a fundamental flaw with React Context or if we're not using it correctly?  Put another way, can the Context code be modified such that Component 3 and the entire App don't re-render with each keypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that React's default behavior is to always render recursively.  When a parent component renders, React will re-render every descendant component in that subtree.

When you have a root component that is storing state and putting it into context, a `setState()` in that root component causes it to re-render, and React will then cause all the children to render as well.

To avoid this, you'd need to add a `React.memo()` (or `PureComponent` or use of `shouldComponentUpdate`) on the `AppInner` component to keep it from re-rendering when its parent renders.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response!  One point I'm hoping you can clarify: The way you've described things, is it correct to say that you don't consider this code example to illustrate a flaw with Context?  Rather, we just need to add some extra code to eliminate the extra renders?

Comment: Effectively, yes.  This is really standard React behavior and performance optimization.  Lift state up to make it available to components that need to access it, identify excess rendering, optimize rendering those subtrees as necessary.  The trick here is that the context values need to be accessible to the whole tree, but you don't want an update to force rendering _all_ components - just the ones that are subscribed to the context. So, you have to block the default render immediately inside the component rendering the context.